# How to manually Controller which role claims to be added to user in ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions, roles, asp.net-core-identity

I have to make an authorization system for an organizational app. They ask me to use Role/Permission concept for their app ...

I want to user Role Claim as some sort of permission and when I add a user to a role , I want the user get all role Claims  ; but in some case I want to be able to remove a roleClaim/permission fro user claim list ...

Well let me explain it , I want to have something like this :

```
Role                RoleClaim ( I intend to use it as Role Permission ) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
WelfareDep          IssueNewRequest
WelfareDep          AcceptRequest
WelfareDep          RejectRequest
```

and have something like this for users:

```
User          Role             UserClaim ( User Permission )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jhon          WelfareDep       IssueNewRequest/AcceptRequest/RejectRequest
Mark          WelfareDep       IssueNewRequest/AcceptRequest/RejectRequest
Rose          WelfareDep       IssueNewRequest
Joe           WelfareDep       AcceptRequest/RejectRequest
```

but as far as I searched , Role Claims are automatically adding to userClaim which have the role ....

I want to have a UI view and controller which role Claim to be add to user (user claim) ...

What should I do?

Comment: The point of role claims is to add all of it claims to the users claim list. If you only want a specific claim to be assigned to a user, use UserClaims instead of RoleClaims to assign it

Comment: in my designg , a role can have n roleClaim (role-permission) ... and all role and its role claim should be added to user as permission .... but in some case an admin want to  remove just one specific permission from user without removing its role .... so i should handle this situation .... I can make something like PermissionGroupTable->PermissionTable and UserTable -> UserPermissionTable without any problem but I really don't want to mess with default Asp.net Identity entities ....